# Change fragment by button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I have to create a sort of view that consist in few fragment that were selected by a "next button". I have a fragment called FragmentSearch that contain a button, when I click the button, I want to go to the next fragment, the FragmentBoxOffice but I don't know how I can do this. 
I tried to do with inflater.inflate in the setOnClickListener of the button but this seems not working. Also I tried to create all the things in a single fragment, using the setVisibity to do a sort of change of the view, but also this not working.

```java
public class FragmentSearch extends Fragment implements SortListener{

...
@Override
public View onCreateView(  LayoutInflater inflater,   ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(fragment_search, container, false);

    Button but =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(fragment_box_office, container, false);

        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
}
```

The XML file:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/search"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.altervista.ilpixelmatto.superfilm.Fragment.FragmentSearch">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="frame1"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@id/text11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="frame1" />
</RelativeLayout>



<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


</LinearLayout>
```

How to do this?

Comment: do you want to use same button to switch from one fragment to another

Comment: no, every fragment have a button for navigate to the next or the prev fragment.

Comment: in situation like this you might risk error by accessing button which supposed to be in last fragment instead of next fragment, best solution would be Scrollable tab you will get a better effect as well and your code would be readable as well

Comment: The problem is that the fragment is yet in a scrollable tab.. I can't add a second scrollable tab inside another one. I have to make a sort of questionary where the user answer some question in this fragment and later scroll at the other fragment in the scrollable tab

Comment: avoid nesting tabs within other tabs, Google doesn't encourage this pattern. Read this http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage

Comment: Yes i know it.. This is the problem indeed! XD  I have to use this button for switch from one fragment to other in the scrollable tab, for NOT use another scrollable tab :)

Comment: than within your fragment make a root linear layout with button and fram layout, and change content for frame layout with different fragments using that constant button :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only proper way to show a fragment is using `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction`. Replace your `onClick()` with:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();  
    FragmentBoxOffice f = (FragmentBoxOffice) fm.findFragmentByTag(FragmentBoxOffice.TAG);
    if (f == null) {
      f = new FragmentBoxOffice();
      fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, f, FragmentBoxOffice.TAG)
        //.addToBackStack(null);  // uncomment this line if you want to be able to return to the prev. fragment with "back" button
        .commit();
    }
}
```

Then in your activity layout you need a placeholder `ViewGroup` called `fragment_container` that will be a parent for the fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Both fragments should have their own layouts which are placed into the fragment_container in the activity layout.

Comment: What is the .TAG attribute from FragmentBoxOffice?

Comment: Just an arbitrary string that the FragmentManager keeps as a map key for each Fragment. You see how in findFragmentByTag() you can search with this tag. 
ps. The only requirement is to have different tag value for each fragment.

Comment: ok, I tried, but the problem is that the "FragmentTransaction ft" have to be an int value and it still not working.. when I click the button, nothing seems to happen >.< thanks for the help.. It's about 3 hours that I'm trying xD

Comment: Sorry, i wrote the code blindly. Just ignore the return value of commit. You don't need it. I fixed my answer.

Comment: ok, the problem is that the fragment don't recognizes the button click. I tried to add a onClickListener to the button or to the fragment, but the fragment don't recognize the event.